# SSL Environment variables during external authorization

Tags: apache, apache2, authorization, mod-auth-external

I am using a custom authorization script on my apache server to authorize users, something like this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145571/apache-authorization-for-the-allowed-users

However, as part of my authorization script I want to query the client's certificate. When my authorization script gets executed, the SSL environment variables are not set, even though I have already passed a valid client certificate to the server.

Is there a way to query the client certificate in the server authorization script?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that mod_auth_external's code assembles the environment for the external process from a very short list of variables and you cannot add to the environment.

The only conceivable place you could pass this down is to stuff is by stuffing it into the Host or Cookie header then extracting it in your PW program.

Both are a pretty big hack and you'd have to protect it being spoofed.

Comment: Or extend mod_authz_external to add a PassEnv like function.